# Load data from excel file into a temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, temp-tables, database-administration

I needed to load 100,000 rows of data from an excel file into a temporary table that I created using "on commit preserve rows". But somehow the most efficient methods did not seem to populate the temporary table due to session issues?

I used Toad to Import Table Data and it showed that x amount of records are imported. But when I select from the temp table, it was empty. Then I generated a bunch of insert scripts and saved them in a notepad.sql and called it from toad editor using @/script/location/notepad.sql and hit F5. It ran and showed how many records were inserted. Again the temp table was somehow still empty. So, I decided to run a random insert script manually in the editor and it showed up in the temp table. I believe the methods that didn't work are not considered to be the same session?

I haven't try SQLLDR but I am assuming it will not work judging from the methods I tried. Can someone confirm? I can't access SQLLDR so I won't know.

Is there anyway to get this to work? I can't run the insert scripts manually. That will be time consuming and Toad can't take that many scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle temp tables created with `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` are session-specific, so the data put into them is only visible within a single session, and for the duration of that session. Toad may be creating a separate session for each window and thus data which is populated from one window/session isn't visible from another window/session. The fact that you can run an insert script and then select the data back suggests this may be the case if both operations were done from the same window. I expect you'd see the same behavior if you used SQL*Loader to load the tables because the load would run in one session and the data would be discarded when the session terminated. Best of luck.